# JMeter connection with SSAS cubes ( SQL Server Analysis Services )

Tags: jmeter

I have to connect Jmeter tool with SSAS cubes ( SQL Server Analysis Services ). So I can execute MDX query and check the performance and load testing of SSAS cube.

Please some one guide me how can I setup connection with SSAS Cube and which driver I need to use (as available with JMeter 5.0) or do I need to install external driver to connect.

Please let me know , Is this possible to connect JMeter with SSAS Cube or not? If Yes, please guide me how to do this with example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try using [olap4j driver](http://www.olap4j.org/) from [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), the example code can be found at [olap4j github page](https://github.com/olap4j/olap4j#writing-a-simple-program)
2. Under the hood of SSAS instances lives [XMLA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187178(v=sql.90)) protocol which is basically SOAP over HTTP so theoretically you can use normal [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) combination so query the SSAS. Check out [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) chapter of JMeter user manual for details.
3. There is a proprietary [SQL Analysis Services JDBC Driver](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/ssas/jdbc/) which can be used normally with [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) as for [any other database](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html).